# How to remove a specific item from the localstorage as well?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to delete the ITem of the saved Leads as shown in the shared Codepen Code but Still couldn't be able to remove the item from the local storagre and then render the exist ones only

I can achive that click on the trash Icon {Delete} the item from the list but when page refereshed appeared again due to localstorage

Please advise how to remove the item from the local storage as Well!!

**CodePen:**

```
`    https://codepen.io/SaoudElTelawy/pen/poZpXbO
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the item from localStorage using the .filter() function.
Like that:

```
const leads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myLeads'))

const filtered = leads.filter(element => 
    element !== value
)
localStorage.setItem('myLeads', JSON.stringify(filtered))
```

Notice that you have to get the value from myLeads, you can do that by adding a DataSet to the button like that:

```
 `
      <li>
          <a target='_blank' href='${myLeads[i]}'>
              ${myLeads[i]}
          </a>
          <button data-item="${myLeads[i]}" onclick="deleteBtn(event)" id='delete-item'>
          <i class="fa-regular fa-trash-can"></i>
          </button>
      </li>
    
  `
```

I Also implement an onclick event to not need to iterate the document object.

Now you have to also disable the pointer event from fa-trash-can to prevent the target from the event be the trash can.

I made a code to remove the clicked item from myLeads:

```
const index = myLeads.indexOf(value);
if (index !== -1) {
 myLeads.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The code get the item index with the value from the dataSet and remove it from the myLeads array.

The final code function have to looks like that

```
function deleteBtn(event) {
 const value = event.target.dataset.item

 const leads = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myLeads'))
 const filtered = leads.filter(element => 
  element !== value
 )
 localStorage.setItem('myLeads', JSON.stringify(filtered))

 const index = myLeads.indexOf(value);
 if (index !== -1) {
  myLeads.splice(index, 1);
 }
 renderLeads();
}
```

Hope i helped you and happy coding :)

Comment: Perfect Solution and working totally fine, thanks for the explanation Pedro.

Comment: & Everyone. Why when I tried to make it chrome extesnion deleting a speicifc item is not working at all!